# Group elements of a long list in python based on the element name

Tags: python

I have a long list like below which I have sorted based on the (element[0], element[3], element[2]), respectively. By element, I mean digits between underlines.

```
list3=['20180406_145813_4_1.jpg',
 '20180406_145813_5_1.jpg',
 '20180406_145813_6_1.jpg',
 '20180406_175827_10_12.jpg',
 '20180406_175827_11_12.jpg',
 '20180409_190651_7_2.jpg',
 '20180409_190651_8_2.jpg',
...]
```

Now, I want to split the list based on element[3].My desired result is:

```
[['20180406_145813_4_1.jpg',
 '20180406_145813_5_1.jpg',
 '20180406_145813_6_1.jpg'],
 ['20180406_175827_10_12.jpg',
 '20180406_175827_11_12.jpg'],
 ['20180409_190651_7_2.jpg',
 '20180409_190651_8_2.jpg'],
...]
```

I have this code that prints each name as a list. I don˙t know how to group by element3 in this code:

```
for imagename in list3:
    element3 = imagename.split("_")[3]
    for j,m in groupby(list3):
        print(list(m))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

list3 = ['20180406_145813_4_1.jpg',
         '20180406_145813_5_1.jpg',
         '20180406_145813_6_1.jpg',
         '20180406_175827_10_12.jpg',
         '20180406_175827_11_12.jpg',
         '20180409_190651_7_2.jpg',
         '20180409_190651_8_2.jpg']

result = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(list3, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[3])]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['20180406_145813_4_1.jpg', '20180406_145813_5_1.jpg', '20180406_145813_6_1.jpg'], ['20180406_175827_10_12.jpg', '20180406_175827_11_12.jpg'], ['20180409_190651_7_2.jpg', '20180409_190651_8_2.jpg']]
```

The above [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is equivalent to the following `for` loop:

```
result = []
for _, group in groupby(list3, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[3]):
    result.append(list(group))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (**No importing anything)**:

```
list3=['20180406_145813_4_1.jpg',
       '20180406_145813_5_1.jpg',
       '20180406_145813_6_1.jpg',
       '20180406_175827_10_12.jpg',
       '20180406_175827_11_12.jpg',
       '20180409_190651_7_2.jpg',
       '20180409_190651_8_2.jpg',
       ...]

res = []
for first, second, third in zip(*[iter(list3)]*3):
    res.append([first, second, third])
```

Just append a list of `first, seconds, third` to the `res` list

```
print(res)

[['20180406_145813_4_1.jpg', '20180406_145813_5_1.jpg', '20180406_145813_6_1.jpg'], 
 ['20180406_175827_10_12.jpg', ...]]
```